# Multiple definitions for User type graphql

Tags: ruby, graphql

I've defined the following GQL type:

```rb
class Types::User < GraphQL::Schema::Object
  field :firstName, String, null: true
  field :lastName, String, null: false
  field :email, String, null: false
end
```

I'm now trying to include it in my root-level QueryType as followed:

```rb
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    # Add root-level fields here.
    # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.
    field :user, [Types::User], "Users who can see this list", null: true do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end
    def user(id:)
      ::User.find_by(id: id)
    end

    # TODO: remove me
    field :test_field, String, null: false, description: 'An example field added by the generator'
    def test_field
      'Hello World!'
    end
  end
end
```

However the error I'm getting is:

> Multiple definitions for `User`. Previously found InputTypes::UserType (Class), then found Types::User (Class) at Query.user

Thoughts on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: no experience with graphql but in class QueryType you have user defined two times, once as a field field :user and once as a method def user(id:)
seems wrong to me

Comment: try with renaming your field :user to :permitted_users or something like that

Comment: @peter so that would work however I identified the issue seems to be related to the second argument (the return type). When I change this from `[Types::User]` →  `String` I don't get the error. But this return type obviously wrong

Comment: I changed the name name of the type file so something other than `User` and it's now working.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, I made an answer of my comment, could you please accept it ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have no experience with graphql but in class QueryType you have user defined two times, once as a field field :user and once as a method def user(id:) seems wrong to me.

Try with renaming your field :user to :permitted_users or something like that.